# How to have Lua script changes during runtime take effect / reload script?

Tags: objective-c, lua

I am doing the below in C++/Objective-C app to load a lua script. Works fine, lua_getglobal successfully gets me the value of "testnum". However the value never changes when I update the script during the application run and the next time I go through this part of the code path.

```
 L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_settop(L, 0);

    int err;

    NSString *  luaFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"lua"];
    err = luaL_loadfile(L, [luaFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]);


    err = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    if (0 != err) {
        luaL_error(L, "error: %s",
                   lua_tostring(L, -1));
        return;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "testnum");

    int num = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
```

The lua file (Test.lua) is simply

```
testnum = 100
```

I'm changing the value of testnum but it always remains 100 (or whatever it was set to at the start up) in the C++/Objective-C application. I can even delete the testnum var entirely and it's still 100 and lua_getglobal does not complain (except if I do that at the start up), num's value will be whatever it was at the start up of the main application. What is needed to reload the script and get whatever the latest number while the application is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it roughly right but I don't think Lua is the issue here, the issue is that the files in the bundle won't change until you rebuild the application.

If you were just loading a file rather than using a bundle then what you have would work.

Comment: I'm only getting the path of the file using NSBundle, that is, for populating luaFilePath. That should not be changing anyway. luaL_loadfile still loads the file.

Comment: Actually you're right, it's the Xcode/iOS bundle build system that results in this. The file I am editing is not the one being loaded - it's loading the one in the app bundle. That's good I have the reason now, still not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Easy enough actually, at least if running on the Mac using the simulator. Simply change the luaFilePath variable to directly wherever the lua file is on the machine. Tested and it works. That's all I'm interested in anyway because on the device I will not have any runtime changes. Great, thanks a lot John.